# how to get mod_rewrite to appear in php.ini

Tags: php, apache, windows-server-2008

I'm running apache 2.2, php 5.3 on windows server 2008 R2.

I've modified modified `httpd` in the folder:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\conf
```

and uncommented

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

I then restarted apache.

On a side note, is having just these two folders in the root apache folder normal?
[image]

I navigate to `phpinfo.ini` and do not see `mod_rewrite` in this list:

[image]

```
**How can I get `mod_rewrite` to be loaded into `phpinfo.php`?**
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

mod_rewrite is not a php module. It is part of apache and gets executed independently from php. That said, you get it to work with the following line in htaccess:

```
 RewriteEngine on
```

You also need to make sure that in your httpd.conf, AllowOverrides is enabled:

```
  AllowOverride all
```

This is important as many httpd.conf ship by default with allowoverride none

Comment: thanks so much!! would it appear in phpinfo.ini when it's working?

Comment: if you have set `AllowOverride all`, just create a file named `.htaccess` with the content `rewrite engine on ` in your webroot folder

Comment: "rewrite engine on"  this is the only text that appears in this file?

Comment: @MaxGherkins i did it, and still dont see mod_rewrite

Comment: it will not appear in phpinfo - it is not a php extension, it is an apache module

Comment: @YounElan but phpinfo.ini shows the mods available from apache. i showed that in the picture in my q

Comment: there are several http.conf files, one in conf\, another in conf\original, another in conf/original/extra

Comment: i was looking in the wrong installation instance of apache :), if i already have this line in htaccess DirectoryIndex index.php index.html  where would i put rewrite engine on?

Comment: when i added RewriteEngine on, i am getting INTERNAL SERVER ERROR

Comment: some are saying `rewrite engine on`... some are saying `RewriteEngine on`... which one is it?

Comment: RewriteEngine On , I am fixing the answer